# PDFSharpCore bookmarks / outlines are coming through corrupt

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharpcore

When including bookmarks / outlines in a PDF generated with PDFSharpCore e.g.

```
document.Outlines.Add("Coversheet", pdfPackPage, true, PdfOutlineStyle.Bold, XColors.Red);
```

These are coming through corrupt in the generated PDF ("Coversheet" comes out as "cßcæﬂ¢áPaÜ‰ÆP8kÖ^⁄2Éõ‡"). If i switch back to PDFSharp, they are not corrupt. Has anyone seen this before or have any insights as to what might be happening or even what this encoding is? I've tested various decoding without result.

If I can work out the mapping for what needs to go in to achieve each character in the alphabet when it comes out, then it might be possible to manipulate the text going in so that it will encode to a readable output. Any solution is welcome.

[image: PDFSharpCore outlines issue]

Comment: Can you supply an example output PDF file?